# Examining which rows are indexed when using partial indexes in YugabyteDB

Tags: postgresql, yugabytedb

I created a table, along with a partial index as shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  email VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL,
  name  VARCHAR
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_idx1 ON users (email) WHERE email IS NOT NULL;
```

Now, I insert the following rows:

```
yugabyte=# INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES ('James Bond', 'jbond@yugabyte.com');

yugabyte-# INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('James Bond');
```

I would expect one of the above rows to be in the index `users_idx1` while another row would not. Is there any way to "inspect" the `users_idx1` index to see which rows made it into the index?

Note that the expected, optimal query plan is being generated depending on the query:

```
yugabyte=# EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='jbond@yugabyte.com';
                               QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using users_idx1 on users  (cost=0.00..4.11 rows=1 width=68)
   Index Cond: ((email)::text = 'jbond@yugabyte.com'::text)
(2 rows)

Time: 128.927 ms
yugabyte=#
yugabyte=# EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='James Bond';
                          QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------
 Foreign Scan on users  (cost=0.00..102.50 rows=1000 width=68)
   Filter: ((name)::text = 'James Bond'::text)
(2 rows)

yugabyte=# EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM users WHERE email IS NULL;
                          QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------
 Foreign Scan on users  (cost=0.00..100.00 rows=1000 width=68)
   Filter: (email IS NULL)
(2 rows)
```

I just want to examine the index, like so (this query would fail):

```
select * from users_idx1;
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is maybe a way get this information with [pageinspect extension BTREE functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pageinspect.html#id-1.11.7.31.6).

But this requires to understand low level PostgreSQL internals. And I am not sure that you can use this extension with Yugabyte (does Yugabyte use the same storage code for tables and indexes as PostgreSQL ?).

Comment: Ah I see... the storage is fully changed in YugabyteDB, so guessing this would not work. Is this extension a way to directly inspect the raw pages or data files?